# Retrieving a day name from a date in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a format for a date like so
`08/11/2015` which is `mm/dd/yyyy`

Is there a way to get my date set `08/11/2015` and find out what the day name is (ex: Monday, Tuesday, etc) in jQuery?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With javascript this would be the way:

```
var weekday = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

var a = new Date('08/11/2015');
alert(weekday[a.getDay()]);
```

Comment: Why it is giving wrong output for Date: 28/03/2017. This ans shows Wednesday whereas its Tuesday??? @baao

Comment: After changing the date format to MM/dd/yyyy ,it is giving right result.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

'date' is not a concept in jQuery, but it is in vanilla javascript.

You can do this:

```
var d = new Date('08/11/2015')
d.getDay();
```

`getDay()` will return an integer from 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday) which you can then map onto a string for that day of the week.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used jquery or javascript before, but a quick trip to an interpreter and the documentation led me to this...

```
js> myDate = new Date('08/11/2015')
Tue Aug 11 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
js>
```

so if you just pass your timestamp to Date() and then use some pattern matching or string manipulation on the first part of the result, you can find out which day it was. Hope that helps!

Comment: Haha sorry for the repeat answer..apparently I should have refreshed my page before I posted

Answer (score 0):

You have to enumerate your own values:

```
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";

var d = new Date();
var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/):

`moment("2010-10-20 4:30", "dddd");`

I know that it is an external dependencies, however it helps when dealing wienter code hereth different locales.